MongoDB index usage
Good day! I have a situation with mongoDB index usage.
I have a request
db.my_collection.find({ "$and": [ { "expires_at": { "$ne": ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z") } }, { "expires_at": { "$lte": ISODate("2024-03-29T16:00:00Z") } }, { "operation.updated_at": { "$lte": ISODate("2024-03-29T16:00:00Z") } }], "operation.status": 3, "is_in_some_state": true, "system_type": "type3", "some_status": 1 })

I have a database with a million records. I created indexes
operation.status_1_expires_at_1
// some other indexes for other requests
expires_at_1_operation.updated_at_1_operation.status_1_is_in_some_state_1_system_type_1_some_status_1

I expected that second index, the exact one that matches, will be taken for requests, but when I do explane() I see that operation.status_1_expires_at_1 index is taken.
So, first question, how/why can it be?
If I tell mongo to use second (exact) index (with Hint option) I get a 30% faster search.
I tried to create some other indexes just to see if something changes and when I created system_type_1 index I got even faster search.
Here comes second question - why? Isn't exact index better?
Summary

operation.status_1_expires_at_1  - 1 second+ request
expires_at_1_operation.updated_at_1_operation.status_1_is_in_some_state_1_system_type_1_some_status_1 - ~700 milliseconds request
system_type_1 - 70 milliseconds request

Did some aggregation to show data representation.
db.my_collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$system_type",count:{$sum:1}}},{$sort:{count:-1}}])
{ "_id" : "type1", "count" : 637289 }
{ "_id" : "type2", "count" : 295798 }
{ "_id" : "type3", "count" : 80788 }
{ "_id" : "type4", "count" : 5 }

Even if I make search with type1 as system_type I can see that only system_type_1 index is used. Why?
Will be gratefull for help.

Your query conditions can be broken down into the following three simple query conditions:
const condition1 = {
  expires_at: { $ne: ISODate('0001-01-01T00:00:00Z') },
  'operation.status': 3,
  is_in_some_state: true,
  system_type: 'type3',
  some_status: 1,
};

const condition2 = {
  expires_at: { $lte: ISODate('2024-03-29T16:00:00Z') },
  'operation.status': 3,
  is_in_some_state: true,
  system_type: 'type3',
  some_status: 1,
};

const condition3 = {
  'operation.updated_at': { $lte: ISODate('2024-03-29T16:00:00Z') },
  'operation.status': 3,
  is_in_some_state: true,
  system_type: 'type3',
  some_status: 1,
};

The order of composite indexes is crucial (The Secret Behind How Databases Use Indexes). The index expires_at_1_operation.updated_at_1_operation.status_1_is_in_some_state_1_system_type_1_some_status_1 won't be of much help for the query with condition3. As the condition on expires_at in condition1 involves inequality, the index won't be much help there either. The reason this index is faster than operation.status_1_expires_at_1 is simply because all columns are present in the index, and the database doesn't need to read data from disk for filtering.
You should create an index as follows:
{
  'operation.status': 1,
  is_in_some_state: 1,
  system_type: 1,
  some_status: 1,
}

The order of these fields depends on the distribution of your data; the fields that can filter out more data should come first. If necessary, you can create two indexes:
{
  'operation.status': 1,
  is_in_some_state: 1,
  system_type: 1,
  some_status: 1,
  expires_at: 1
}
{
  'operation.status': 1,
  is_in_some_state: 1,
  system_type: 1,
  some_status: 1,
  'operation.updated_at': 1
}

expires_at and operation.updated_at should come last.

Works perfectly with first index, thank you! Btw, is there a reason to use some kind of sliding window? I mean the  { "expires_at": { "$ne": ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z") } } condition looks really heavy to process, isnt it?

Regarding { "expires_at": { "$ne": ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z") } }, my suggestion is to add a boolean field called is_valid_expires_at. This field would be true when expires_at is not equal to ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"). Then, include this field in the index.

The request will become like this: db.my_collection.find({ "$and": [{ "expires_at": { "$lte": ISODate("2024-03-29T16:00:00Z") } }, { "operation.updated_at": { "$lte": ISODate("2024-03-29T16:00:00Z") } }], "operation.status": 3, "is_in_some_state": true, "system_type": "type3", "some_status": 1, "is_valid_expires_at": true })
